# How can I filter records of a DirectUS collection based on values on a many-to-one relationship?

Tags: filter, collections, relationship, directus

I am using DirectUS version 8.3.1

I have a many-to-one relationship between user_membership and user. 
The table user_membership is where we store the years of membership for a user and then we have several lines for a user, one per year of membership.

I have configured the interface with a many-to-one relationship and I have set the template {{name}} - {{email}} for the user.
I can easily add, update or remove lines into the table user_membership. The table has more than 20000 lines and I need to filter them. From DirectUS, how can I find for instance all the lines for user "John - john@smith.com" among my 20000 lines?

Is the solution to add a one-to-many relationship into table user and to go through the table user to search for all memberships a good solution? Will DirectUS add something into my original database schema if I create this user to user_membership relationship?

Many many thanks

Dominique

Comment: In fact I found a solution thanks to the fantastic possibilities of the filtering functions and I filter by the userId. And it works fine but I have first to go to user collection get the user id and come back to "user_membership". A better idea?